# Align start of table text with main text

Tags: tables, alignment

Consider this example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent\lipsum[1][1-2]

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  A & B
\end{tabular}

{
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  C & D
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

It has the output:

[image]

I would like to align the start of the text in table with the beginning of main text.

in the second table I try to use `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` which achieves this effect with the undesired result of disappearance of separation between table columns.

What would be a better solution?

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}` will remove the `\tabcolsep` from the beginning of the first column only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the `\tabcolsep` untouched everywhere else but remove it you can use the `@{...}` notation. From section 2.11.6 of the [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε](https://ctan.org/pkg/lshort?lang=en) (`texdoc lshort`):

> [image: The column separator can be specified with the <code>@{...}</code> construct. This command kills the inter-column space and replaces it with whatever is between the curly braces. One common use for this command is explained below in the decimal alignment problem. Another possible application is to suppress leading space in a table with <code>@{}</code>.]

In your document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent\lipsum[1][1-2]

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  A & B
\end{tabular}

{
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  C & D
\end{tabular}
}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
  A & B
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the particulars of the `tabular`, a tabular stack might be ideal.  There are never any leading or trailing gaps on the stack; yet, the intercolumn gap is fully settable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabstackengine}
\strutlongstacks{T}
\begin{document}
\noindent\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\tabularLongunderstack{ll}{ Aa & B\\C & Dd}

\noindent
\setstacktabulargap{2em}%
\tabularLongunderstack{ll}{ Aa & B\\C & Dd}
\end{document}
```

[image]